# how to validate email before enter to the home page flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication

i'm trying to validate my email before the user can enter to the home page.
the problem is when i fill the email and password user with aaany thing it give the access without any check.
here is my code for sign in page

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and this is the code of sign up screen

[image]
[image]

Comment: Once you have done the registration, you should send a email verification link to the email address with whom the registration did. Then, in you login system you have to implement, if the email is verified, then it can be login, otherwise verify the email.

Comment: how can i do it please on my code

Comment: On Stack Overflow, do not share pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: in the first i want to copy the code and format it but it not accept it it give me error so i upload it on images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is all about `validating the email for formatting`, then what you can do is shown below. Put it in your email address validator you are submitting the data for `Login/Register`

```
validator: (value){
    Pattern pattern = r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    // Null check
    if(value.isEmpty){
        return 'please enter your email';
    }
    // Valid email formatting check
    else if(!regex.hasMatch(value)){
       return 'Enter valid email address';
    }
    // success condition
    else {
       email = value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You will be good to go with this :) Happy learning.

Comment: Inside your `TextFormField()'s Validator()` for `Email`. I will make the changes in the code  for you to make you clear on that :)

Comment: I have made changes in the code, which will looks exactly like your code with `Email Validator` check :). It is okay to ask, we're here for that purpose only @MrFlutter

Comment: thaank you a lot it works, but i have a simple problem here again when i tap any email address it accept it despite i don't sign up with this mail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216957/discussion-between-alok-and-mrflutter).

Comment: Hey @MrFlutter, click on the above link, to continue the chat in the StackOverFlow's private room